# Etymology of “that” as both pronoun and conjunction

Tags: etymology, history, historical-change

“That” can be used both as a pronoun and as a conjunction. For example,

> I know *that* it is raining.

> Give me *that*.

This is unique to English as far as I know. In French and Spanish, for example, the two uses of “that” are distinct (c.f. “que” vs. “ça”). Looking online, this is true for non-romance languages as well.

Is there evidence that English originally had two words for “that”, depending on its context, but the words eventually merged? Wiktionary suggests such a merger would have occurred before the development of Old English.

Comment: German, to which English is closely related also has a subordinator derived from a determinative (read pronoun), Spanish similarly has ‘que’. linguistics.stackexchange.com would be the best place to ask this interesting question!!!

Comment: The Germanic complementizers (_that_ and _dass_, for instance) come from the [demonstrative PIE *to- root](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=to-), whereas the Romance complementizers (_que_ and various contractions) come from the [interrogative/relative PIE *kʷo- root](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=k%ca%b7o-). Complementizers can come from any variety of linguistic phenomenon; with gerunds it's a suffix, with infinitives it's prepositions, with tensed clauses it's a *to- word _that_ and a *kʷo- word _what_.

Comment: that is a deictic pronoun in English (Give  me that.)

Answer (score 3):

In Old English, they often used *þe* as a generic complementizer and relative pronoun. It could stand alone as a relative pronoun of sorts, or it could be added to adverbial phrases to make them conjunctions. For example, *for þæm* essentially meant *therefore* (i.e., *for this (reason)*) and *for þæm þe* meant *because* (i.e., *for this (reason) that...*). More to the point of your question, though, is that it is, of course, just another fossilized case form of *þæt* or related adverbial formation.

It seems that IE languages originally had three sets of pronouns: interrogative, relative and demonstrative. The neuter stems for each were (with some simplification for the purposes of this answer): ***kwo-**, ***yo-** and ***to-**. In daughter languages, usually one of these ended up dying out and its function was taken over by another one. In Latin and the Romance languages, ***kwo-** (e.g., *quod*) was used for both interrogative and relative. In Germanic, ***to-** (e.g., ***þat**) was used for demonstrative and relative, while ***kwo-** (e.g., ***hwat**) was used only for interrogative. Later, English switched towards using the ***hwat** based words for relatives as well. This was *not* the case in Old English, where it patterned like modern German. That is, *þæt* could be demonstrative or relative, while *hwæt* was only interrogative. In Old English, you would say *se mann þone (þe) ic geseah* where as in Modern English, you would say *the man who(m) I saw*. Note that we still allow *the man that I saw*, a holdover from an earlier period.

As it happens, *ca* is no relation to any of the above. It is derived from a Vulgar Latin compound of ***ecce hoc**, which we could translate as *this here*. And *hoc* itself is built from some rare demonstrative stem ***gho-** plus a common deictic particle ***ke**. None of those are related to the aforementioned roots.

References:

- A Guide to Old English by Bruce Mitchell, notably sections 168 through 171.
- New Comparative Greek and Latin Grammar by Andrew Sihler, sections 378-384, NB 378a, which discusses the putative origin of relative constructions in PIE.

Don Ringe discusses this stuff too, but I can't find my copy right now.